# On Symfony2 with Doctrine2, does Object = Entity?

Tags: php, object, entity, symfony, doctrine-orm

Let's say I have a `User` class :

```
$user = new User(1);
$user->setName('Bob'); // save "bob" to database with ID 1
$user->setGender('Male'); // save "male" to database with ID 1

echo $user->getName(); // display bob
echo $user->getGender(); // display "male";

echo $user->getDesignation() // display "Mr. Bob"
```

Now, in Symfony2, with Doctrine2, it seems that `Entity` is an object which is used to made link with the database. So I think all the `setName()`, `setGender()`, `getName()` & `getGender()` functions should go inside a file which is in the `Entity` directory of a Bundle (because those functions UPDATE or SELECT data from the database).

But what about `getDesignation()` ?

```
public function getDesignation() {
  if ($this->getGender() == 'Male') return "Mr. ".$this->getName();
  else return "Ms. ".$this->getName();
}
```

Is it OK to put a function which has absolutely no link with the database in an Entity ? Is it not a bad practice ?

Comment: not bad practice - but your returning "Mr" everytime ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it OK to put a function which has absolutely no link with the database?

Yes that's okay. But look closely, it is still somewhat "linked" to the database as it makes use of the gender and name data which originally comes from the persistence layer (database).

> Is it not a bad practice?

That's not at all bad practice, in fact it's something very useful. It helps you to make use of the persistence layer in your model objects while decoupling your code from the database access.

Answer (score 1):

It works if your page is always displayed in english, if you need to translate the website into another language, maybe you should create an additional class to handle with the Symfony translator and the entity in order to get multi-langague titles. Another and simpler approach would be to return only the person title "mr." in a separate function like:

```
public function getDesignation() {
  if ($this->getGender() == 'Male') return "Mr." else return "Ms.";
}
```

Because you could easily transale it in your template {{entity.designation|trans}}

Anyway I just wanted to contribute a little, but the short answer would be: Yes, you can use the entity to handle extra-fashion-methods beyond the basic getters

Regards