# Custom global configuration values in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony

I'm aware of using custom configuration values for my custom services, but what if I have global configuration values that I wish to use everywhere? A define would save my ass, but I'm sure the DI container has a more elegant approach.

I need a few global keys, so, how do define them in Symfony 2?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9209176/global-access-to-symfony2s-configuration-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define them in parameters.ini, and then you can do `$container->getParameter('blah');`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [the container](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/definitions.html#getting-and-setting-container-parameters). [This page](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html) shows how to define services, but you can do the same with parameters.