# Symfony: How to use translation component in entity __toString?

Tags: symfony, localization, internationalization, symfony2-easyadmin

Yes, I know this has been asked before and discouraged, but I have a good use case for that. I am interested in learning the view-oriented supplementary approach.

The use case:

I have an entity, say `Venue (id, name, capacity)` which I use as collection in EasyAdmin. To render choices, I require this entity to have string representation.

I want the display to say `%name% (%capacity% places)`.

As you've correctly guessed, I require the word "**places**" translated.

I could want to do it

1. directly in the entity's `__toString()` method
2. in form view by properly rendering `__toString()` output

I have no idea how to implement either but I agree that the first approach violates the MVC pattern.

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Displaying it as `%name% (%capacity% places)` is just a "possible" representation in your form view so I would shift this very specific representation to your Form Type.

What can belong in the `__toString()` method of your **Venue** entity:

```
class Venue 
{
    private $name;

    ... setter & getter method

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->getName();
    }
}
```

**messages.en.yml**:

```
my_translation: %name% (%capacity% places)
```

Next your **Form Type** using [choice_label](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choice-label) (also worth knowing: [choice_translation_domain](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choice-translation-domain)) :

```
use Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface;

class YourFormType extends AbstractType
{
    private $translator;

    public function __construct(TranslatorInterface $translator)
    {
        $this->translator = $translator;
    }

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add(
                'venue',
                EntityType::class,
                array(
                    'choice_label' => function (Venue $venue, $key, $index) {
                        // Translatable choice labels
                        return $this->translator->trans('my_translation', array(
                            '%name%' => $venue->getName(),
                            '%capacity%' => $venue->getCapacity(),
                        ));
                    }
                )
            );
    }

}
```

& also register your form type as a service in **services.yml**:

```
your_form_type:
  class: Your\Bundle\Namespace\Form\YourFormType
  arguments: ["@translator"]
  tags:
    - { name: form.type }
```

Comment: And this goes into EasyAdmin how?

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a more or less complex solution for that problem, see my answer on this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54038948/2564552